# How do I make the table width constant regardless of the value change in my <select> element?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have `select` element inside a table cell in my **HTML** table:

```
<div style="width: 100%;">
    <table border="2">
        <tr>
            <td><b>Colony name:</b></td>
            <td><div style="width: 100%;"><select name="colony_name" id="colony_name" 
             style="text-align-last: center;" onclick="get_names()">
             <option value="default" selected="selected_code">
             Select your colony name</option>
             </select></div></td>
         </tr>
     </table>
</div>
```

When I click on the `<select>` dropdown, the function `get_names()` is called which returns a list of values received from the server:

```
function get_names() {
    let $select = $("#colony_name");
    $.ajax({
      url: '/server.php',
      type: 'POST',
      data: { "input": "names" }, 
      dataType: 'json', 
      success: function(response) {
        response.sort();
        let selectedValue = $select.val();
        let html = response.filter((e, i, a) => a.indexOf(e) === i).map(item => 
       `<option value="${item}">${item}</option>`);
        $select.html(html).val(selectedValue);
      },
      complete: function() {}
    });
}
```

Now the thing is that when I click on the `<select>` the dropdown gets populated and it's width increases, as a result the width of the table too increases. I want to keep the width of the `<select>` constant, so that the table width too remains constant.

I tried giving a responsive size such as `5em` to the parent div of the `<select>` like this:

```
<td><div style="width: 5em;"><select name="colony_name" id="colony_name" 
     style="text-align-last: center;" onclick="get_names()">
     <option value="default" selected="selected_code">Select your colony name</option>
</select></div></td>
```

In this case, the width of the table remains constant, but the width of the dropdown is increased to the point that it goes out of the table. How do I fix this issue? Please guide me.

Comment: Add `overflow:hidden` to the div?

Comment: Or give the select field itself `width: 5em` to begin with, and remove the wrapper div.

Comment: The problem with `overflow:hidden` is that it will then hide the `[v]` of the `select`

Answer (score 0):

To keep the width of the  element constant regardless of the value change, you can set a fixed width for the  element itself. This will prevent the width of the  element from changing when the options are populated.

You can do this by adding a style attribute to the  element and setting its width property to a fixed value. For example, you can set the width to 150px like this:

```html
<select name="colony_name" id="colony_name" style="text-align-last: center; width: 150px;" onclick="get_names()">
```

This will ensure that the width of the  element remains constant at 150px even when the options are populated.

if you want to prevent the  element from overflowing the table cell, you can add the CSS property "overflow: hidden" to the parent div element like this:

```html
<div style="width: 100%; overflow: hidden;">
    <select name="colony_name" id="colony_name" style="text-align-last: center; width: 150px;" onclick="get_names()">
        <option value="default" selected="selected_code">Select your colony name</option>
    </select>
</div>
```